# Is there a legal way to find out if Saad Hariri somehow arrested or not?

Tags: saudi-arabia, lebanon

Lebanese Prime Minister [Saad Hariri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saad_Hariri) announced his resignation while on a visit to Saudi Arabia. Several sources have said Saudi Arabia is holding Hariri with restricted freedom– a claim that the Kingdom has denied.

How can someone find out if he somehow arrested or not?
Can the UN do something helpful?
Can the Lebanese president do anything?

Comment: Less snarkily, no. There's no legal way due to lack of independent institutions and checks and balances in KSA. It's not like it has an independent judiciary system with a formal set of rules and FOIA processes.

Comment: So a trip to KSA would be dangerous, even for a head of a state?

Comment: depends on how much reason KSA has for snatching you. As a random StackExchange poster, probably not much of a reason. As a head of state that is effectively allied with KSA's main enemy, maybe.

Comment: @user1 A prime minister isn't head of state. They might be head of government, but I don't know the Lebanese constitution.